# Count employees added on each day of each week in separate columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have to distinctly divide `"Employee"` table on base of week and then get count of employees added on the week days.

Example result:

| Week | Sunday | Monday | Tueday | Wednesday | Thrusday | Friday | Saturday | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/26/2023 - 12/02/2023 | 27 | 26 | 27 | 25 | 27 | 27 | 28 | 187 |
| 12/03/2023 - 12/09/2023 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 26 | 27 | 27 | 27 | 191 |
| 12/10/2023 - 12/16/2023 | 27 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 27 |

Column description:

```
Week Column : [Start Date of the Week] - [End Date of the Week]
Sunday Column : Count of Employees Added on Sunday.
Monday Column : Count of Employees Added on Monday.
...
Total Column : Total Number of Employee on that Week.
```

Input table `"Employee"`:

| "Id" | "Name" | "Department" | "JoiningEpoch" | "JoiningDate" | "CreatedEpoch" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Robin | Developer | 1702706400 | 2023-12-16 00:00:00 | 1702706400 |
| 2 | Emp2 | HR | 1702965600 | 2023-12-09 00:00:00 | 1702965600 |
| 3 | Emp3 | DevOps | 1701237600 | 2023-11-29 00:00:00 | 1701237600 |

Comment: As this is about PostGreSQL, I suggest you remove the MySQL tag

Answer (score 2):

To get the count of employees added on each weekday for each week, you can use the `date_trunc()` function to group the employees by week and weekday, and then use the `count()` function to count the number of employees in each group. Something like this:

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('week', JoiningDate) AS week,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM JoiningDate) = 0) AS sunday,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM JoiningDate) = 1) AS monday,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM JoiningDate) = 2) AS tuesday,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM JoiningDate) = 3) AS wednesday,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM JoiningDate) = 4) AS thursday,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM JoiningDate) = 5) AS friday,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM JoiningDate) = 6) AS saturday,
  count(*) AS total
FROM employee
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week;
```

See if it works!

Comment: Correct, but [pasted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) from ChatGPT.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [aggregate `filter`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) clause to get day counts in separate columns, shift from [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) Monday week start back one day to see your week ranges start on Sundays by subtracting `1` and use [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) or set your [`DateStyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting to achieve the desired date format: [Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ukvNLJtH)

```sql
set DateStyle='SQL,MDY';

SELECT
  to_char("Week",'MM/DD/YYYY')||' - '||("Week"::date+6)::text AS "Week",
  count(*)filter(where dow=0) AS "Sunday",
  count(*)filter(where dow=1) AS "Monday",
  count(*)filter(where dow=2) AS "Tuesday",
  count(*)filter(where dow=3) AS "Wednesday",
  count(*)filter(where dow=4) AS "Thursday",
  count(*)filter(where dow=5) AS "Friday",
  count(*)filter(where dow=6) AS "Saturday",
  count(*) AS "Total"
FROM (SELECT date_trunc('week', "JoiningDate")::date-1 AS "Week", 
             extract(DOW FROM "JoiningDate") dow 
      FROM "Employee")AS a
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY "Week";
```

| Week | Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/26/2023 - 12/02/2023 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 12/03/2023 - 12/09/2023 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 12/10/2023 - 12/16/2023 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

There's also a [`crosstab()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#TABLEFUNC-FUNCTIONS-CROSSTAB-TEXT) function in `tablefunc` extension that can pivot results this way automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Week Column Should display [Start of the Week]-[End of the Week]. i found a way to get the DayofWeek and then do some Interval add and substract to get the start and end date of week. 
LIKE :

```psql
TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP("JoiningEpoch") AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago' - (("DayOfWeek") || ' days')::INTERVAL ,'YYYY-MM-DD')
|| ' - ' ||
TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP("JoiningEpoch") AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago' + ((6 - "DayOfWeek") || ' days')::INTERVAL ,'YYYY-MM-DD')  AS "Week",
```

Comment: @RohitRehni Sure, I added that in my last edit. One thing I'd be afraid of is that your column layout  and week ranges suggest you assume Sunday to be the first day of a week, while PostgreSQL assumes based on ISO standard 8601 it's the last, even though it's returning DoW of 0 (in different systems, Sunday is either 0 or 7, but other days keep their numbers from 1 to 6). Based on what you do, you might run into inconsistent behaviour unless you always double-check everything is set up to follow your day numbering.

Answer (score 0):

As I can only use the Postgres 9.5 version for this,

We can get the "DayOfWeek" Colum Using `DOW` on Date and this dow will have a day of the week as Sunday (0) to Saturday (6).

Now To get a Week Start and End date, we can subtract "JoiningDate" with "DayOfWeek" Column using the `INTERVAL` type for [Start of the Week Date] and add 6 - "DayOfWeek" `interval` to "JoiningDate"  for [End of the Week Date] also can use `TO_CHAR` for format `YYYY-MM-DD` for "Week" Column.

Later to sum the query we can use `Group BY` in the Week Column with `Sum` and `Case` Statement in the "DayOfWeek" Column to get each day's sum of employees.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ("DayOfWeek" =  0)   THEN "EmployeeCount" ELSE '0' END )  AS "Sun",
    SUM(CASE WHEN ("DayOfWeek" =  1)   THEN "EmployeeCount" ELSE '0' END )  AS "Mon",
    SUM(CASE WHEN ("DayOfWeek" =  2)   THEN "EmployeeCount" ELSE '0' END )  AS "Tue",
    SUM(CASE WHEN ("DayOfWeek" =  3)   THEN "EmployeeCount" ELSE '0' END )  AS "Wed",
    SUM(CASE WHEN ("DayOfWeek" =  4)   THEN "EmployeeCount" ELSE '0' END )  AS "Thr",
    SUM(CASE WHEN ("DayOfWeek" =  5)   THEN "EmployeeCount" ELSE '0' END )  AS "Fri",
    SUM(CASE WHEN ("DayOfWeek" =  6)   THEN "EmployeeCount" ELSE '0' END )  AS "Sat",
    SUM("EmployeeCount")                                                    AS "Total",
    "Week",
FROM (
    SELECT

        -- Week is Sunday to Saturday instead of Monday to Sunday
        -- "2021-07-18 - 2021-07-24" Week
        TO_CHAR("JoiningDate" - (("DayOfWeek") || ' days')::INTERVAL ,'YYYY-MM-DD')
        || ' - ' ||
        TO_CHAR("JoiningDate" + ((6 - "DayOfWeek") || ' days')::INTERVAL ,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Week",

        "DayOfWeek",
        COUNT("Id")  AS "EmployeeCount"
    FROM (
        SELECT
            "Id",  TO_TIMESTAMP("JoiningEpoch") AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago' ) AS "JoiningDate",

            -- The day of the week as Sunday (0) to Saturday (6), Using INTEGER instead of dayname to increase Perfomance
            EXTRACT(DOW FROM DATE( TO_TIMESTAMP("JoiningEpoch") AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago' ))   AS "DayOfWeek",   -- 0-6  DayNumber
        FROM "Employee"
    ) AS sq
    GROUP BY 1,2
) AS sq1
GROUP BY "Week"
ORDER BY "Week"
```